# Intermittent wifi connection in ubuntu 18.04 in HP 15q ds 0017tu laptop

Tags: networking, wireless

My HP Notebook 15q ds 0017tu is connecting to the wifi from any modem intermittently. But if i provide the same wifi from a mobile it is able to connect without any hiccups.

My wireless hardware details :

```
description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: c0:e4:34:3a:4a:b9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de driverversion=5.3.0-42-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.139 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:130 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you rephrase your question and focus on problem?
If you want to see wireless connection please look at

> Settings--> Wi-Fi --> Visible Networks
>
> and see if you see your Wi-Fi from mobile.
>   I hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that my PC doesnot have any problem to connect to mobile hotspots. But if i try to connect to a wifi from a router / modem, even though it connects for a while, starts disconnecting abruptly showing that unable to connect whereas the wifi modem/ router is working fine.

Comment: so a sustained uninterupped wifi connection is not happening even though my mobile is able to use the wifi from the same router with ease.

Comment: Also if i switch to a wired connection to the same modem, there is no issue.